# How to remove map markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to implement a map system where the user can select a point of origin and destination as two different markers.

When the user long clicks on the map they could select a button to use this location as a start or end point.

```
    case (R.id.setStart):
        markerStart = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(this.startPoint)
        .title("Start")
        .draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));       
        outputName = rGC.getStringFromCoordinates(this.startPoint.latitude, this.startPoint.longitude);
        autocompleterStart.setText(outputName); 
        break;
    case (R.id.setEnd):
        markerEnd = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(this.endPoint)
        .title("End")
        .draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

However, when the user repeats the same process (select a new location as start/end), I want  to be able to remove the previous marker. So if they select the same START button, the previous marker for start is removed and a new one is created.

Is there a way to check if a particular marker exists on the map. I tried adding `marker.remove();` but it gives me a nullpointerexception.

```
        case (R.id.setEnd):
        markerEnd.remove();
        markerEnd = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(this.endPoint)
        .title("End")
        .draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If your getting a null point exception it is because `marker` is null. Try adding `if(marker!=null)` before it so that command is skipped the first time when the marker is unset.

Comment: @Robadob It still doesn't work since i need to initialize both markers at the start of the method. So it does not remove anything.

Comment: Perhaps you should store the markers somewhere inside your class? The only other way you can regain a handle to your markers would be from a user clicking them.

Comment: Thanks, i got it working, I just placed the markers outside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use method which i have implemented in my app and working fine...for me

```
LatLng  latpoint;

MAP.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // MAP.clear();
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                latpoint = point;
                marker = MAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(latpoint.latitude,
                                        latpoint.longitude))
                        .title(point.toString()).draggable(true)
                        .visible(true));

            }

        });
```

Comment: This is right too, my mistake was that i initialized the markers within the method.